# Problem regarding the logic in my program

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

I have been trying to make a bot that warns someone after they swear. I have written the code and it compiled perfectly but it does not work. There is no response. I have tried everything but I don't know whether it is a jda issue or my logic which is causing the error.

```
public class corefunction extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onGuildMessageReceivedEvent(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] badwords = {"this", "array", "contains", "bad", "words"};
        for(int i = 0; i < badwords.length; i++) {
            String[] input = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");
            User user1 = event.getAuthor();
            if(input[0].equalsIgnoreCase(badwords[i])) {
                 event.getChannel().sendMessage("no swearing " + user1).queue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you think the error is with declaring the variables inside the 'for' loop, that is not the case as I fist declared it outside the loop and the same error occurred. Then I declared it inside the loop only to find out no change. If it is needed, the following code below is my main class.

```
public class main {
    public static JDA jda;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws LoginException {
        jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("my token here").build();
        jda.getPresence().setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
        corefunction object = new corefunction();
        jda.addEventListener(object);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: You are not overriding the method. It it called `onGuildMessageReceived` not `onGuildMessageReceivedEvent`.

Comment: lol im so dumb. thanks